# exact_extract() with different extents

Tags: r, raster, spatial, terra

I'm using exact_extract() in r. Should the raster and sf object have matching extents? Or is it enough if only the CRS:s match? And additionally the raster and sf resolutions are different: the raster resolution is 16 x 16 and the polygon 250 x 250. Should I make a coefficient to make the results match?

This is the raster information:

```
dimensions  : 7348, 13467, 19  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 16, 16  (x, y)
extent      : 261856, 477328, 6628832, 6746400  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : ETRS89 / TM35FIN(E,N) 
source      : memory
```

And this is the DF information.

```
Simple feature collection with 682 features and 13 fields
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 301500 ymin: 6651000 xmax: 462000 ymax: 6728500
Projected CRS: ETRS89 / TM35FIN(E,N)
```

Answer (score 0):

`exact_extract` does not need the same extents for raster and polygon to extract the summary statistics. The same thing applies to resolution, even if talking about the resolution for a polygon dataset doesn't make sense, at least you can use the term " nominal scale", but however it is irrelevant for zonal statistics between raster and sf